# Perguntas sobre hospedagem são off-topic?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Vi esta pergunta sobre o assunto e como não foi fechada por nenhum moderador e sem votos para fechamento (até o momento), fiquei na dúvida, e até postei uma resposta mas removi pela dúvida:

[Hospedagem de site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318601/hospedagem-de-site/318661)

Esse tipo de pergunta não cabe no site e deveria ser fechada?

Comment: Eu fiquei na dúvida. Ele fala sobre como servir o portfólio, mas também não dá detalhes da estrutura que já tem hoje. Servir arquivos estáticos não me parece off-topic. Coisas específicas do Hostgator para servir arquivos me parece off. Marquei como "não clara", entretanto, já que não há informações o suficiente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A maior parte da pessoas que atuam em fechamentos (falando dos brasileiros apenas):

- Não acessam o site nos sábados e/ou domingos
- Muitas pessoas acessam o site durante até no máximo 19:00 horas, são raras as que navegam pela madrugada

A pergunta foi feita no Domingo e em um horário aonde as pessoas geralmente estão aproveitando o ultimo *"dia de folga"*

> Esse tipo de pergunta não cabe no site e deveria ser fechada?

São off-topics, configurar DNS, CNAME e hospedagens podem ser coisas muito especificas e muitas vezes beira ao *"suporte técnico"*, ele mesmo informa isto:

> Eu tenho dois domínios em uma hospedagem

Isso depende do tipo de ferramentas que o serviço fornece, ele teria que no minimo informar se usa Apache, Nginx, IIS, LightTTPD, etc (para fazer um apontamento) e se ele tem controle sobre isto, ou se for mesmo tudo via Cpanel no minimo é off-topic mesmo.

> ... achei estranho não ter sido fechada pelo moderador que fecha tudo

Moderadores são pessoas (acredite), eles também podem querer ter o fim de semana livre e só volta na segunda em horário comercial, no fim de semana é bem comum ter uma série de perguntas assim e se o tal moderador que citou for quem imagino, ele atua sempre que pode, mas ele também tem projeto pessoais paralelos, o que as vezes não é possivel dedicar tempo a coisa que nós como comunidade podemos resolver, afinal de contas temos em nossas mãos as ferramentas.

Moderadores são principalmente para resolver casos problemáticos de verdade, como usuários baderneiros, spammers, manipulações e etc. Não tem como eles resolverem tudo, fora que o moderador não precisa dominar todas linguagens e tecnologia, o que ele precisa é resolver o problemas graves.

Nós "moderamos" também (o conteúdo) e o que as tecnologias que você domina bem e que acredita a postagem é off-topic, vote para fechar, colabore com a comunidade.

Inclusive o ultimo voto que faltava foi meu, porque cheguei agora, ontem eu no máximo acessei o chat para conversar com dois outros usuários e depois sai, então nem tive tempo de olhar o site.

Comment: Paciencia é a alma do negocio. Ou as vezes basta postar no chat que a galera que for acessando vota.

Comment: @Articuno excelente sugestão! Mudaria a frase para: *basta postar no chat que a galera que for acessando vai checar se é mesmo caso de fechamento e então votar conforme acreditam ser melhor.* - Só para evitar mal entendidos.

Comment: Verdade, acho que o moderador não pode ficar sobrecarregado. Quanto ao moderador que citei, é esse mesmo que vc pensou rs... mas eu não fiz alusão a ele com conotação pejorativa, acho que tem é que fechar tudo mesmo (o que for ruim), e ele tem feito isso, ao meu ver, com muita competência.

Comment: @sam não vi como pejorativo, só quis dizer que ele é uma pessoa bastante ativa, as vezes ele fica muito no site e outras vezes ele parece estar ausente, pois ele tem um projetos pessoais, que inclusive alguns de nós acompanhamos, como palestras, ai ele tem que se ausentar mesmo.